# getting #VALUE ERROR in Excel IF function

Tags: excel, if-statement, valueerror

trying to do nested IF statement in one formula:

[if condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izzU9.png)

I get `#VALUE ERROR` with a formula containing multiple `IF` conditions in cell `H12`:

`=IF(AND((C6/C4)<=1,C10=0),1+0.4*C6/C4, IF(AND((C6/C4)<=1,C10>0),H13-((1-H13)/(C12*TAN(C10))))), IF(AND((C6/C4)>1,C10=0),1+0.4*ATAN(C6/C4), IF(AND((C6/C4)>1,C10>0),H13-((1-H13)/(C12*TAN(C10)))))`

[image: Excel calculation]

Based on this:

[image: Reference]

[image: Reference]

I'm using Excel 2013.

Comment: Have you tried using "Show calculation steps" or other debugging facilities provided by Excel?

Comment: H12 references H13, which has an error, so I'd suggest starting by fixing H13.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer on : [This site](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php)
IF function takes only three parameters (conditions)